# Is it possible to use an image icon that is opaque?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm using an cartoonish icons for system users and I noticed that when the background is transparent in the file, it gets ugly black in CRM on the form. So I made it obliquely white, which resolved the problem half way through. The other half is that the sucker looks as the image below shows.

[image]

Can it be resolved somehow or do I just need to get used to it and live with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics CRM doesn't support transparent PNGs for the `entityimage` field.

The ugly alternative is to use the bar color (#002050) as background of your images.

EDIT: in case you want to have fun with the `entityimage` field and a webcam, check my tool

[Dynamics CRM Mug Shot](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/08/dynamics-crm-mug-shot.html)

Comment: How will *#002050* do the trick? The background needs to be dark blueish on the bar shown in the image in my question **but** it needs to be white on the form's full view of the user profile. Or did I misunderstood? (+1 for a cool feature, sadly, I have no time to test it at the moment but knowing you, I trust it'll work when I need it in the future, hehe.)

Comment: the blu color is for the top bar, not possible to store 2 images (1 for the top bar, 1 for the user profile)